# What the CIRCUMFIX option `+` sign does in Hunspell?

Tags: format, hunspell

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/Documentation/) in the docs it shows this about circumfixes (source code [here](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/blob/master/tests/circumfix.aff)):

```
# circumfixes: ˜ obligate prefix/suffix combinations
# superlative in Hungarian: leg- (prefix) AND -bb (suffix)
# nagy, nagyobb, legnagyobb, legeslegnagyobb
# (great, greater, greatest, most greatest)

CIRCUMFIX X

PFX A Y 1
PFX A 0 leg/X .

PFX B Y 1
PFX B 0 legesleg/X .

SFX C Y 3
SFX C 0 obb . +COMPARATIVE
SFX C 0 obb/AX . +SUPERLATIVE
SFX C 0 obb/BX . +SUPERSUPERLATIVE
```

That is, you have the "circumfix" around the base word like:

```
leg- (prefix) AND -bb (suffix)
```

I can't tell how this is represented from the docs alone, can you elaborate?

The first prefix is given ID `A`, and it has 1 rule. Given any following character (`.`) we don't replace anything (`0`) but we add `leg`... What is the `X` in `leg/X`, is that just *flagging* `leg` as a circumfix, and that's it?

The second prefix is the same style, just a longer prefix `legesleg`, which is flagged as being part of a circumfix.

The suffix now.... 3 rules, add `obb` after the last character, with no replacements. What is `+COMPARATIVE` and the other `+...` stuff? In the docs it appears to be called `morphological_fields`. I think they describe it briefly here:

> Hunspell’s dictionary items and affix rules may have optional space or tabulator
> separated morphological description fields, started with 3-character (two letters and a colon) field IDs...

But that seems like something different. So what does the `+...` mean?